# Mailgun Mailing Lists 'Sender' Header

Tags: api, email, mailgun

I have a client with a number of Mailgun mailing lists. Some of them are public, some readonly. When people send a message to a public list, they are then shown as the 'sender' when the message is received (rather than the Mailgun list address). I believe this is causing some recipient mailservers to mark messages as spam - as they do not appear to originate at the sender's server.

Anyone got any experience of this problem? I think it'd be solved by setting the list address as the sender, but this doesn't seem to be an option in Mailgun.